# Facebook Graph API Album Endpoint is deprecated?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using the graph api (through android SDK and graph explorer) to get a page's posts, when I get to a post of a page that has multiple images in a post it becomes an album.

Example post response

```
"message": "Test Multi-Photos",
      "full_picture": "",
      "from": {
        "name": "TestPage",
        "id": ""
      },
      "attachments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "media_type": "album",
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 405,
                "src": "",
                "width": 720
              }
            },
            "type": "album",
            "title": "Photos from TestPage's post",
            "target": {
              "id": "147710857059579",
              "url": ""
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "_147710857059579"
    }
```

When I try to use the `target.id` to get the album photos

I believe the url would look like this

`https://graph.facebook.com/147710857059579`

I get a response saying that the endpoint is deprecated

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "AhhiY7ohbb5SoXdFNDZnHhU
"
  }
}
```

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/) does not say anything about it being deprecated so how do you get the album photos?

Comment: Concatenating page id and "album" id with an underscore seems to work - but also appears to be pretty much the same post object again. Requesting the `attachments` from that, I get the same data again as before. My guess, these are not "real" albums? But the `subattachments` structure appears to contain all the images.

Comment: @CBroe subattachments? how do I get those?

Comment: I am getting those automatically, when testing in Graph API Explorer. But you can also try and explicitly append `?fields=attachments{subattachments}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get photos from an album post you have to add `subattachments` to the attachments fields in the query.

Example using the Android SDK

```
parameters.putString("fields", "message,full_picture,from,place,attachments{media_type,media,type,title,description,target,subattachments}")
parameters.putString("limit", "10")
```